# I lost the button in my vscode terminal to expand to full-size and cover the editor window

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

In my vscode there used to be an upwards-pointing caret in the upper right of the integrated terminal.  Clicking on it would toggle the terminal pane to be expanded and cover the editor pane above.  I used it frequently.  Now it is gone.  Is there some setting to make it re-appear or did someone decide it wasn't needed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

VSCode : Terminal - Maximize panel size

[image: 1]

Do you mean 'Maximize panel size' button? You can bring that back by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P, type 'Customize Layout' and hit enter.

VSCode : Customize layout  panel alignment

[image: 2]

At panel alignment, choose 'Center' it will bring that back.

source: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144688